# How to access a native byte array via Java java.lang.foreign API

Tags: java, java-native-interface, project-panama, java-21

I want to access a PKCS11 library from Java via FFI/Panama. Let's say we have the following packed group layout under Windows x64:

```java
GroupLayout groupLayout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
    MemoryLayout.sequenceLayout(64, JAVA_BYTE).withName("slotDescription"),
    MemoryLayout.sequenceLayout(32, JAVA_BYTE).withName("manufacturerId"),
    JAVA_INT_UNALIGNED.withName("flags"),
    MemoryLayout.structLayout(
        JAVA_BYTE.withName("major"),
        JAVA_BYTE.withName("minor")
    ).withName("hardwareVersion"),
    MemoryLayout.structLayout(
        JAVA_BYTE.withName("major"),
        JAVA_BYTE.withName("minor")
    ).withName("firmwareVersion")
).withName("CK_SLOT_INFO");
```

A naiv approach would be to write a helper method:

```java
public static String getString(MemorySegment memorySegment, int offset, int length) {
    byte[] slicedData = new byte[length];
    MemorySegment slicedMemorySegment = memorySegment.asSlice(offset, length);
    slicedMemorySegment.asByteBuffer().get(slicedData);
    return new String(slicedData);
}
```

Then call it with the offset and length:

```java
String manufacturerId = MemorySegmentUtils.getString(memorySegment, 64, 32);
```

Because PKCS11 uses different packing/padding, I don't want to hardcode these offsets and lengths. Using `getUtf8String` like mentioned in  [Java VarHandle to a C string with java.lang.foreign API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314769/java-varhandle-to-a-c-string-with-java-lang-foreign-api) doesn't work because the char strings are fixed and not zero terminated.

So How can I use a `MethodHandle` to read these bytes:

```java
MethodHandle methodHandle = groupLayout.sliceHandle(MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("manufacturerId"));

// What to do now?
String manufacturerId = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution looks like the following:

```java
public static String getFixedString(MemorySegment memorySegment, GroupLayout groupLayout, String name) throws Throwable {
    MethodHandle methodHandle = groupLayout.sliceHandle(MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement(name));
    MemorySegment namedMemorySegment = (MemorySegment) methodHandle.invokeExact(memorySegment);
    byte[] namedData = namedMemorySegment.toArray(ValueLayout.JAVA_BYTE);
    return new String(namedData);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, you can replace `getBytes` with: `namedMemorySegment.toArray(ValueLayout.JAVA_BYTE)`

Comment: If you want to get an advantage out of the slice handles, you should store them in `static final` fields rather than (re)acquiring them for each operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JornVernee - I knew there was an easier way!

Comment: @Holger Yes, indeed. I will refactor each group template + method handle calls into own platform dependent classes. At the moment I am still in the "try out" phase. But FFI is really impressive. So great to replace platform dependent JNI code :)

Comment: Btw is there a MemoryLayout.paddingLayout(int) method that can serve as a no-op element if a condition is (not) met? On Windows x64 everything is 1 byte packed whereas on Linux it is 4/8 bytes padded and manual padding in the group layout is required. Is there a way to unify the group template?

Comment: @swaechter No, layouts are platform dependent. To determine which layout you need the right way, you need a C/C++ compiler, which isn't bundled with the Java runtime (but it _is_ bundled with jextract). I recommend having 2 different layouts, one for each platform, and then select one or the other based on which platform you're running, then derive all handles from that layout.